# Nesting a h:selectOneRadio inside another h:selectOneRadio 's f:selectitem

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I want to create a group of radio buttons inside an option of another radio button.

It has to look like this.

```
Radio Title1
O Yes
   Radio Title2
     O Yes
     O No
O No
```

When I try the following code the items are rendered as two rows of a table, but when i keep another component inside this selectone radio item, it keeps out of the table, So I am not able to achieve what I want.

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="reportDestination" layout="pageDirection">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes" />

    <h:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection">
        <f:selectItems itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes"/>
        <f:selectItems itemLabel="No" itemValue="No"/>
    </h:selectOneRadio >

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="No" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Is there anyway to do it?
Any input is appreciated like a reference or a logic or anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever seen anything like that in the real world? You should separate the controls. You can still achieve nesting, without both controls being physically nested in each other

Comment: Hi Kolossus, I got a feature requirement in my current project, where the second selectoneradio control should be nested inside the first one both physically and functionaly.

Comment: I haven't seen such a thing, but you might want to shop around for some custom JQuery-ish control. Stock JSF doesn't provide that

Comment: I found a solution by myself. Will update the solution soon.

Comment: @user2617611: Soon?